# Database Audit-Trail and reconstruct previous result

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have an table that stores business contacts and associated info.

Currently each day a copy of all contacts is saved in the table. The table structure looks like this:

```
Date        CompanyName          Description      Address        Industry
20130416    Alpha Corp           bla bla bal      6100 main st.  Finicial 

20130417    Alpha Corp           bla bla bal      6100 main st.  Finicial 
20130417    Beta Corp            bla bla bal      6500 main st.  Consumer

20130418    Alpha Corp           bla bla bal      6120 main st.  Finicial 
20130418    Beta Corp            bla bla bal      6500 main st.  Consumer
```

This illustract what happens when 20130417 "Beta Corp" is added, and when 20130418 "Alpa corp" is modified.

I wanted to change it to have audit-trail capability.
Currently what's in my mind is a table to store all current entries (introducing new field CompanyID int auto-intrement)

```
CompanyID CompanyName Description Address Industry
```

And another table to store all historical changes

```
CompanyID CompanyName Description Address Industry ChangeTime Action User
```

Most of the queries will be to get contact list as of today, which will be easy under the new schema, but I still want to be able to do queries like "Get the contact list as of 20130416", which should return 1 row. And it feels like rather dirty to construct historical data by current entries and change log.

What would you do under similar situation? And the reasoning?

Best,

Comment: check out Hibernate Envers. It will do the dirty work for you. Or at least copy the schema that they use.

Answer (score 3):

An audit trail generally identifies who changed what. You're looking for something substantially different. You want your database to answer questions like `select * from table_name where (data appears as it did on 2013-01-15);`.

As far as I know, Richard Snodgrass published the earliest comprehensive work on solving this kind of problem using SQL. He breaks time-oriented databases (and tables) into these categories.

- Valid time tables: these capture "the history of a changing reality."
- Transaction time tables: these capture "the sequence of states of a changing table."
- Bitemporal tables: these implement both valid time and transaction time tables.

I think you're looking for bitemporal tables.

His book [Developing Time-oriented database applications in SQL](https://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/tdbbook.pdf) is available from his faculty web page at the University of Arizona as a PDF download. Since it's free, there's no excuse for not skimming it before you dig yourself into a hole.  Read the code carefully for integrity constraints. (Get those wrong, and your database is almost worthless.)

Comment: Very helpful. Decided to try the way mentioned in chapter 9.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve worked with databases that have had to maintain audit history.  For this there was a field called “Timeframe ID.”  If the value of this field was -1 that meant the record was in the past.  If it was 0 the record was current.  In some cases it would be a 1 meaning it was a future record (these were rare).

These tables also had a “Modified” date field.  So if a user makes an update you just update the current Timeframe 0 record to -1 and insert a new row with the modified data.  This way you can tell who changed what and when.  Or, in your case where the data is updated daily the modified date will be the date the record was loaded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What query would you do to get the records valid for a particular day

Comment: Just use the modified date in the where clause.  Are you using MS SQL?  You can use WHERE ModDate BETWEEN DateTimeA AND DateTimeB.  Or use the YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY() functions.

Comment: What about PK constrain? I wanted the companyID to be PK but storing old entry in the table will result in multiple entry with the same companyID

Comment: Correct.  You wouldn't be able to use the company id as a primary key using the suggested model. Storing the old data in the same table would require a unique row id for the primary key.  You could add a revision ID column and key/index off the companyId + revisionId.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track Johnyy.  My recommendation would be to split the tables like you've proposed.

The solution from Travis might work ok, but consider that the historical snapshots will grow very large over time. If you separate them the queries on the current day will run fast. If you keep them together, over time the queries will naturally get slower and slower (granted it might take a while to notice).

The idea from Travis of having a revision ID paired with the company ID is good. I've called this the "snapshot" ID in the past. I have a snapshot ID in the table and then another table that has the details of the snapshot that I can join to.

For example:

Company Table:

```
CompanyID, CompanyName, Description, Address, Industry
```

Company Historical Table (where Snapshot ID and Company ID represent your key):

```
SnapshotID, CompanyID, CompanyName, Description, Address, Industry
```

Snapshot Table:

```
SnapshotID, CreateDate, CreateDateTime
```

I would strongly consider zeroing out the time the snapshot was created just to make the queries a bit easier.  If they really represent just one day, the time becomes an annoyance. You can still store it to see the actual time it was done though.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to think about. First what is the purpose of auditing? Auditing is differnt than maintaining time oriented data. If you are auditing, you will need the information to be able to reverse the change. So saving the old data is critical but it ialso critical to save teh date teh change happened and who or what application made teh change. This way if you put a new version of the application out on Wednesday and on Friday a bug is discoverd where it changed alot of things it shouldn;t be changing, you know exactly which records were changed by that application from wed to Friday and can easily fix the bad change.  real Auditing should always be handled through triggers never the application.

Historical data is different, you do this becasue you need to know the state of something at a point in time. For instnce in an order details table you would want to store the price of an item at the time fo teh order not the price it might be a year later when you query the record. In this case you can store everything in one table and if you have a large database partition it by time.  This involves making the application put in a new row every time the data changes. If you do this, you probably want to create a view to use that shows only the current records. In fact I would change teh name of the table  and create the view with your current tablename to avoid breaking any existing code. This will help you avoid forgetting to put in the qualifiers that get only active data when wrting new code against this table.

Or you can do two tables where old values are moved through a trigger (do not even consider doing the move through the application, for this to work any possible table change has to be handled and a trigger is the only place to ensure this will happen) when the data changes. If you do this, then you will probably want to create a view that unions the two tables together so that you can query all the data.

Comment: Using view to show current active entries is diffidently the way to go if using one table to store current and historical data.